# Possible to create a DYLIB from a C++ DLL project?

Tags: c++, windows, macos, dll, dylib

I have a C++ project that was used to create a DLL.  Is it possible to take that C++ code and create a DYLIB file?  I have only done a tiny bit of work with C++, so I am not sure if this can easily be done.  Basically, I have an app that I rewrote in Python so I could run it on Windows or macOS.  The Windows version of the app is able to use the DLL without a problem.  Now, I would like to use the library with the macOS version of the app.

Comment: As your IDE (you want to use an IDE, right?), take a look at [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) or [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/mac/).  I currently use the former, but I'm thinking of switching over.

Answer (score 0):

In general, of course, it is possible. However, whether it will be an easy job or not depends on whether how the library was written.

- In the best case: you only need to recompile the library in macOS following its build instructions (e.g. typically explained in the documentation or in a `README`-style file in the root of the project).
- In the worst case: the library is not portable at all (e.g. depends on the Windows API) and you won't be able to use it without rewriting it.

A side question is whether you really need the library: it is possible that you can find a Python library to fulfill the same job.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is very limited documentation.  There is nothing in the project that is Windows dependent, so it should be portable to macOS.  It takes several user supplied parameters as input and outputs an array of numbers based on a custom algorithm.  There is not any Python library that would substitute.

Comment: @gpraceman: In that case, it seems likely that you can easily compile it in macOS. Assuming it is compiled using MSVC (Visual Studio) in Windows; I would take a look at its project/solution file to take note of the compilation options. Then I would try to recompile the library using Clang instead of the Microsoft compiler (still under Windows). After successfully testing the newly Clang-built library in Windows, I would then move to macOS and compile it using the same options using Apple's clang (or a custom clang). This approach allows you to take a difference at a time (compiler, then OS).

Comment: I have been able to compile it using MSVC with Visual Studio in Windows and the resulting DLL tested just fine.  However, trying to compile it with Clang has not been as easy for me to get going.  Unfortunately, I have only a little experience with C++ and don't have too much time to dedicate to getting this going on macOS.  I may have to hire someone to get this compiled for me.

Comment: @gpraceman: The errors that you may be getting could be due to the library relying on MSVC extensions/details; or maybe something trivial -- hard to say without more details (i.e. could be a trivial port, or a hard one). In any case, for ports involving C++, I encourage getting a way to thoroughly test the resulting libray (maybe the library comes with a test suite; or maybe you have the means to validate it -- e.g. black box testing). As for hiring, I recommend it, specially if there is no way to easily test the full library (i.e. if the library is poorly written, many details can go badly).

Comment: My issue is more just getting Clang setup.  I've got it installed for use with Visual Studio on Windows.  However, it doesn't appear as simplistic as changing the compiler for the project to Clang.  Visual Studio for macOS doesn't even have C++ as a language option, so porting it over doesn't seem straightforward.

Comment: _Visual Studio for macOS doesn't even have C++ as a language option_ I think you'll find that it infers that from the file extension, although you might be able to override that on a per-file basis should you need to.  Post a few of your error messages (back to your question, please), maybe someone can help you.  Also, make sure your copy of VS is up to date.  MS are moving very fast in this area.  I regularly cross-compile, Windows and Mac, and it works fine for me.  On the Mac, I use Xcode and clang, so there's nothing wrong with clang.